# Update initial value after a request

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I update the initialValues of my model after a get request but it does not update the initial values of my model. If I use a button to call `vm.options.updateInitialValue();` it works. Is this a known bug?

```
jsonService.getJSON().then(function(response){
              vm.model = response.data[0];
              vm.options.updateInitialValue();
        //console.log(vm.options.updateInitialValue); 
      });
```

Example can be found here: https://jsbin.com/doyitaf/4/edit?js,console,output

Click the reset button and it will reset the field to empty instead of the name retrieved through the factory.

Comment: Where is the method updateInitialValue()?

Comment: What do you mean? You can find the method at line 31 and line 38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to wait to compile the form until after the model has arrived. A good approach to this is to use an `ng-if="vm.model"` on the form like [this](https://jsbin.com/bumubu/edit?html,js,output)

```
<form ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" name="vm.form" novalidate ng-if="vm.model">
  <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" options="vm.options">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" ng-disabled="vm.form.$invalid">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.options.resetModel()">Reset</button>
  </formly-form>
</form>
<div  ng-if="!vm.model">
  Loading...
</div>
```

Good luck.